# JavaScript Callback: Reference Error on line 206: ouput2 is not defined

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to create a function that accepts two callbacks and a value that will return a boolean indicating if the passing the value into the first function, and then passing the resulting output into the second function, yields the same output as the same operation in reverse (passing the value into the second function and then passing the output into the first function).

I get the following error and I believe it is probably due to scoping but not sure how to resolve it: `Reference Error on line 206: ouput2 is not defined`

```
function commutative(func1, func2, value) {
  //check to see if invoking cb1 on value then passing output to cb2 as cb2 => cb1
  function func1() {
    let output1 = func1(value);
    return output1;
  }
  
  function func2() {
    let output2 = func2(output1);
      return output2;
  }
  
  function reverseOrder() {
    let output3 = func2(value);
    let output4 = func1(output3);
  }
  
    //return boolean
  if (ouput2 === output4) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

// Test cases:

```
 const multBy3 = n => n * 3;
 const divBy4 = n => n / 4;
 const subtract5 = n => n - 5;
 console.log(commutative(multBy3, divBy4, 11)); // should log: true
 console.log(commutative(multBy3, subtract5, 10)); // should log: false
 console.log(commutative(divBy4, subtract5, 48)); // should log: false
```

Comment: When declaring a variable , the let keyword will give it a scope within what it was created. Meanwhile, If you were to make a variable with the keyword var it's scope will still be global even if inside a function unless use strict is created prior that declaration

Comment: @Sean That would only be true in a block statement like an `if` or a `for`. Using `var` inside a function will still make it local. To move it to the outer scope, you would need to do `var output1, output2, ...;` (or `let`) at the beginning of the `commutative` function, and not use any `let` or `var` inside the inner functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never calling your inner functions, and `output1`, `output2`, etc. are defined locally to those inner functions, not accessible in the scope of `commutative`. Also, you are overwriting the `func1` and `func2` parameters. Try this:

```js
function commutative(func1, func2, value) {
  return func2(func1(value)) === func1(func2(value));
}

// Test cases:
const multBy3 = n => n * 3;
const divBy4 = n => n / 4;
const subtract5 = n => n - 5;
console.log(commutative(multBy3, divBy4, 11)); // should log: true
console.log(commutative(multBy3, subtract5, 10)); // should log: false
console.log(commutative(divBy4, subtract5, 48)); // should log: false
```